# How to set user Windows password in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, ssms

I am using SSMS to interact with a database I have locally on my PC. I also have a software to create reports about data in the database, but first of all I have to connect the software to the SQL Server database.

I'm logging into the database using Windows authentication (credentials `WindowsDomain\username`) which is my PC name and Windows username. At the beginning I didn't set a password and it connected successfully.

But to connect the software to the database, I have to fill in different fields such as Host Name, Port Number, Database Name, User, Password. I can't leave empty the Password field even if I don't have one, so I need to set a password for my Windows username : OK easy, I just have to set the password account in the Control Panel..

I restart my PC and check if I need to fill the password, now, in SQL Server.. But it still connects without any password, the software does not connect the database with that password, and in SQL Server I can't solve it with a query (alter login on my username), error :

> Cannot use parameter PASSWORD for a Windows login.

How can I set a password for this user name ? Or maybe to create a new one with SQL Server authentication or Windows authentication, it's the same for me...

Comment: Please show us which ConnectionString are you trying to use at the moment (with sensitive items blanked out of course)

Comment: What is this software you are trying to connect to the database?

Comment: @PeterB `DRIVER={MicroStrategy ODBC Driver for SQL Server Wire Protocol}; hostname=myHostName; Port=1433; Database=myDBname; AuthenticationMethod=9; Domain=myDomainName; ;`

@TabAlleman it's MicroStrategy

Comment: It seems likely that one of the values of `AuthenticationMethod` could indicate "integrated authentication", in which case the software should not ask for a user name/password. However, the documentation for the MicroStrategy driver isn't very accessible. If the software *insists* on a username/password, it probably does not support integrated authentication at all, and you will need to create a separate, dedicated SQL user in the database. In either case, Windows accounts and SQL accounts have no overlap. Never fill in your Windows password to log in to SQL.

Comment: I found an example, maybe you know it, maybe you don't: **https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/ka1440000009E9QAAU/KB215066-Is-it-possible-to-use-Windows-authentication-to-login**. Also, try **https://www.connectionstrings.com/** maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use password with Windows Authenticationthat is not a correct way and also imposible because Windows AuthenticationLogin is different from SQL Login. 
In Windows Authentication you don't have a password because Windows tells SQL that I trust this user(who is loged in on this computer) so you can trust him